# flask-limiter using a static global key for a limit

Tags: python, api, flask, rate-limiting

I wanted to create a global limiter using the `flask-limiter` extension which applies to all clients who access a specific URL. I didn't see anything for specifying 'global', so I just made the key function a lambda which just returns a value of `global`.

Here is a segment directly from my current source code.

```py
# Streams back the specified media back to the client
@app.route('/stream/<service>/<mediaid>')
@limiter.limit(downloadLimiter, lambda : 'global', error_message='Rate Limit Hit')
def stream(service, mediaid):
   ...
```

I don't see how it would *not* work, but I'm wondering if I've overlooked something.

**Is there a better, more *built-in* implementation for making a limiter's key global to all clients?**

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to do, but didnt flask have a `g` for global?

Comment: I don't really understand what this `g` thing you are talking about refers to, but I'm talking about the use of the `flask-limiter` extension in this question.

Comment: With `lambda: 'gobal'` in place of a key function which usually returns the client IP: 10 requests to a route with a limit of 10, will cause the limit to exceed on the next request, regardless of the connecting IPs (I asume this is what you require).  The only place this will break down is if you deploy with several WSGI workers.  Ensure to use a backend like Redis in this case.

Comment: Okay, good to know since I'm currently deploying production WSGI with ~8 workers I believe. I don't know what Redis is, but I'll look into that.